# Android Studio error cannot resolve 'setJavaScriptEnabled'

Tags: android, android-studio

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

when i try to run it gives me : 
cannot resolve 'setJavaScriptEnabled'

I tried to rebuild , and File>Invalidate Caches/Restart , but no use.
can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines of code:

```
WebView mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

must be inside a method. For instance add them to `onCreate` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't notice that.
But now there is another error appeared, i will try to fix , thanks again

Comment: Okay try fixing it, if it is still hard you can comment it here...we can discuss, I'm still online...